# Dynamically set value of Bootstrap slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I created a slider as below,

```
<input id="brightness" onChange="changeBrightness()" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text"
                    data-slider-min="-100" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="2" data-slider-value="0"/>
```

I need to set value dynamically to this slider. I tried,

```
$("#brightness").slider('setValue', 8, true);
$("#brightness").slider('refresh');
```

But this is not working. How can I do it?

Comment: Not sure, but I guess `$("#brightness").val(8);` would set it to 8?

Comment: Tried it, but not working.

Answer (score 8):

only `$("#brightness").slider('setValue', 8, true);`

refresh with initial values
`$("#brightness").slider('refresh');`

Answer (score 4):

Try the following script:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#brightness").attr('data-slider-value', 8);
    $("#brightness").slider('refresh');
});
```

Comment: Error: cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'... Am getting this error...

Comment: @Nidhish You must make sure that the code runs after Bootrstrap has initialized. (Not sure how to do that in practice though.) You could try running it on a click event or something just to see if it works.

Comment: I loaded bootstrap-slider.js initially. And tried the above code on a button click event. Then getting error "Error: cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'value''...

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of things you could do with the sliders value, dynamically: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7h2zyc0u/2/)

```
var slider = new Slider("#budget-slider-1");
var slider2 = new Slider("#budget-slider-2");

slider.on("change", function(slideEvent) {
  var currentValueSlider2 = slider2.getValue();
  slider2.options.min = 80;
  slider2.setValue(100);
});
```